# UndeliverableException related to Single.zip and possibly bindToLifecycle()

Tags: retrofit2, rx-java2

I recently updated my app to RxJava2 and RxLifecycle3 - I'm further using Retrofit2.
I am seeing a lot of UndeliverableExceptions now when my server requests via Retrofit and RxJava fail. Unfortunately, the stack traces do not reveal where in the code the error happens - only that it probably is a stream using `Single.zip()`.

I looked for emitters / create constructs calling `onError()` but only found `tryOnError()` calls in my app.

Could it be that RxLifecycle's `.compose(bindToLifecycle())` is the cause? In every place I use this call I placed it right above the `subscribe()`  call. 
I know this approach emits `onError()` to cancel the stream. In this case, is the Single disposed properly upstream? Is there a problem with disposing a `Single.zip()` operation residing within a `flatmap()`?

Do you have any ideas what other patterns to look for `UndeliverableException`s?

```
Fatal Exception: io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | <Cause Exception Message>
       at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleZipArray$ZipCoordinator.innerError(SingleZipArray.java:139)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleZipArray$ZipSingleObserver.onError(SingleZipArray.java:175)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleObserveOn$ObserveOnSingleObserver.run(SingleObserveOn.java:79)
       at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:119)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Multiple sources you zip fail which triggers this error and possibly crash. Please read the documentation linked in the error message.

Comment: @akarnokd So upstream cancellation works the same way for calling dispose and emitting `onError()` event and the issue is not related to RxLifecylce?
Would not the whole zipped source be disposed upstream in either case and this would dispose both its sources?
Regarding zipped behavior: If two zipped observable sources trigger an error would it not make sense the second is disposed once the first emits an error? (Or does this happen but is not safe regarding race conditions?) 
If, however, the zip operator awaits the result of the second source would not a `CompositeException` be logical?

Comment: Please read the documentation linked in the error message.

Comment: @akarnokd I did read it multiple times and I fixed UndeliverableExceptions before but I seem to miss the relevant part. Of course, I could implement a global on error handler but I don't know if would suggest this. I would rather treat the error at the cause.
I only ran into undeliverable exceptions when I was calling onError on some type of emitter before.
I don't have that in my code anymore and I don't get the origin of the undeliverable exception - only that it's related to a Single.zip call.

Comment: I further don't understand how one gets a undeliverable exception if both sources of a zip fail since I would expect a CompositeException here, which would not be wrapped into an UndeliverableException. Can you help me on how to catch / prevent the error?

Comment: You can't. In an asynchronous system, many can fail at once and also race with cancellation, so you'd end up multiple errors. Since the protocol only allows one exception per flow, the others have to be dropped/handled in a separate way. The issue with using `Single.zip` for your case is that it wont't wait all sources to terminate because if any of them fails, there is not enough value to call the function with and thus no reason to continue. So you have two options, handle the global error or don't let RxJava know about the error.

Comment: @akarnokd Does that mean that whenever I'm using a combining operator (like zip) and more than one source can emit an error I need a global error handler?

Comment: Have a global error handler or make an a value out of an error, so you can decide in the function what to do: [Single.materialize()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#materialize--).